# Why is PostgreSQL `coalesce` not working as expected/hoped inside a function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, null, coalesce

A simple function that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_to_tsvector(config regconfig, source text)
 RETURNS tsvector
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
RETURN
 to_tsvector(config, coalesce(regexp_replace(source, '\W', ' ', 'g'), ''));
```

And an even simpler query:

```
select
    text_to_tsvector('english', '123'),
    text_to_tsvector('english', ''),
    to_tsvector('english', coalesce(regexp_replace(null, '\W', ' ', 'g'), '')),
    text_to_tsvector('english', null)
```

Results in this:

| text_to_tsvector | text_to_tsvector | to_tsvector | text_to_tsvector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '123':1 |  |  | null |

Take a note on the last column.
[A fiddle is here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b4qwysK8pUwwwckZawKXNX/3)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found the reason.
I was copy-pasting the function definition from another part of the project and didn't notice the `STRICT` part.
Removing it solves the problem.